# How to lower the resolution of my website

Tags: html, css, resolution

I'm trying to make a website that replicates the look of old websites from the 90's. So because of that I'm trying to find a way to downscale the resolution of the entire website, but I still haven't found a way to successfully do this. I've tried setting the width and height of the body but that doesn't work.

An analogy for what I'm trying to do is like how you'd downscale an image to lower it's resolution, so when you do that of course the quality of the picture is worse because there are less pixels. I'm not sure if this is possible or not with a webpage.

Comment: You need to find a font which look like pixelated and all your images make in bad quality. It's the only way I can think of. I.e. Do it all by hand. Plus I found this which might help a little https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: Old websites were not pixelated. You can set a max-width to a global wrapper or something like that. And use small images (both in resolution and file size)

Comment: @digitalniweb ooh alright. i was concerned that this would be the only way to do it, thank you for telling me about it!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add padding to the body tag, i'm not sure this is what you're looking for but it should look something like this

[image: stackoverflow with body padding]

Comment: i just realized this doesn't look that different from how stackoverflow normally looks but i hope it helps

Comment: oh what I meant was that I needed to downscale the website to a lower resolution, because if I use this then this leaves some blank space outside of the downscaled portion

Comment: if all you're content is withing the body and you give it padding and max width that should work like you want it to

Comment: it's actually what i did in that screen by editing the body tag of stackoverflow, you just don't notive because the website looks so uniform at all sizes, and because of the top bar that's not attached to it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).